# Could -Xcomp be in sourcecode not in java compiler parameter?

Tags: java

Could I write something in java sourcecode file so that the result would be same as I had ran the java file with argument -Xcomp?
I want to know it, beacuse I want to send the file to someone else who does not use -Xcomp and I want the output to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You can't do that.

There is no way to set the JVM options for a Java program in that program's source code.  The options are all processed before the JVM starts the application code, and (in nearly all cases) there are no APIs for changing them at runtime.

(One exception to this for properties set using `-D...` options.  It is possible to set the same properties via the `System` properties object.  But to make this actually work, the property values need to be set by application code before they need to be used.  In many cases, it is difficult or impossible to achieve this ... given the way that the respective Java SE functionality initializes itself.)

It is also possible to write a Java program that launches a second Java program.  If you do this, the first program can set any command options it like for the second one.

---

If your output depends on whether or not `-Xcomp` is set, then something is wrong:

- If your application is a performance benchmark, then setting `-Xcomp` is going to give you unrealistic performance figures.
- Otherwise, a difference in output indicates that your code is non-deterministic.  If that is "by design" then you should *expect* differences.  If not, then maybe you have bugs in your code.  (And setting `-Xcomp` isn't going to reliably eliminate non-determinism that relates to platform and hardware differences.)